# Margin and Padding of <Body> Tag

Tags: html, stylesheet, padding, margin

I am writing a very simple HTML code which is listed below. Written in notepad and opening in IE-8 and Firefox (OS: Window Vista).

```
<html>
<body>
    <table border="1"><tr><td>test</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

There is nothing special in the above code, It is creating some space from top left corner.

[image]

Which can be easily removed by using the following code

```
<body style="margin:0; padding:0">
```

Now i have find out the default margin and padding, which is `4` for Firefox and different for IE-8.

```
<body style="margin:4; padding:4">
```

I have some question on this scenario.

1. Why this value is 4?
2. From where this value is coming, is it saved somewhere?
3. Can we modify (configurable) this default value?
4. How these values are different for browsers?

Thanks.

Comment: In at least Firefox, it's always 8px for me. Both from the left as well as from the top.

Comment: @poepje, Yea firefox seems to follow http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. First of all, it's probably `4px` and not `4`. Second, that's just the way the browser vendor decided should be the default.
2. It is saved in the default browser stylesheets.
3. You can, but you **shouldn't**. It differs with each browser. Google it! `How do I change default stylesheet on <insert browser here>?`
4. There probably are slight differences, you should be able to tell... by looking at the default stylesheets :)

That difference is one of the main reasons we as designers use a CSS reset, to normalize all of the CSS awkwardness that follows different browser implementations.

Comment: Worth mentioning - changing a browser's behaviour isn't the solution to anything

Comment: A small note on 3.: That would be only good if the page is intended just for personal use. If it's published on the web and others would get to see the page, they would have the 4/8px margin and thus see a slightly different page than intended.

Answer (score 3):

Browsers have built-in "sane defaults" for the CSS of most HTML elements - this just prevents your page looking completely unreadable if you have pure HTML without CSS, but they are of course intended to be overridden by your own CSS.

The default browser styles are typically referred to as a **"User Agent Style Sheet"** - the following site is a good reference of the various peculiar UA sheets IE has had over the years and also provides ones for other browsers at the bottom:

http://www.iecss.com/

One method a lot of people use to *"normalise"* the defaults so you have the same starting point in all browsers is a **"CSS Reset"** - this is just a snippet of CSS that you place before your own CSS that sets all of the UA styles to the same thing. This is a well known one:

http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/

Comment: Do you have sources to default styles of other major browsers like Chrome and FireFox?

Comment: See the bottom of the page on http://www.iecss.com/ - however this answer is 2 years old, I'm not sure how often that website is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
body{
    line-height: 0
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Add this on top of your stylesheet

```
*{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
```

This eliminated all differences in padding and margin across browsers.

Comment: This is a horrible approach, as the * select will select everything.  And as a consequence, can be considered more specific than other values you may attempt to set elsewhere.  Not to mention removing 'sane' defaults you might not realize you rely on.