# Can't get image to left of the page

Tags: html, css

I want the red image on the left of my page but I think that there is some kind of margin because I can't get it into the corner. The empty space lines op with the images in my menubar but this is in a other div. Does anyone know how i can get the image to the right of the page?

[this is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qcF8.png)

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* algemene opmaak en instellingen body --------------------------------------------------------------------- */
body {
    background-image: url("achtergronden/hout.png");
 width: 100%;
}

html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* logo ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
#Anouk {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
}

#Anouk img{
    display: block;
}

/* menubalk ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
#header {
    height: 80px;
    background: #000000;
}

li {
 display: block;
    float: left;
}

li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
 height: 80px;
}

#contact {
 float: right;
}

/* blauwe stuk pagina homepage en portfolio ----------------------------------------------------------------- */
#homepagina {
 background-image: url("achtergronden/blauw.png");
 width: 100%;
 height: 485px;
}

/* updates -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */ 
#updates {
 height:1000px;
}

#laatste {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-family: oswald, sans-serif;
 font-size: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: bold 700;
}

/* footer --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */ 
#footer {
 height: 85px;
 width: 100%;
 background: #000000;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: right;
}

#facebook img {
 margin-top: 7px;
 padding: 0;
}

#email img {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

```html
<body>
         
            <div id="Anouk"><img src="logo/Hout2.png" width="100%" alt="Logo"/></div>
         
            <div id="header">
    <div id="menu">
              <!--Home-->
                    <li id="home">
                     <a href="index.html">
                         <img src="Iconen/menu/home.png" height="80px" alt="home" 
                      onmouseover="this.src='iconen/menu/home2.png'" 
                            onmouseout="this.src='iconen/menu/home.png'"/>
                     </a>
                    </li>
                    <!--Over Mij-->
     <li id="over">
                     <a href="over.html">
                         <img src="iconen/menu/over.png" height="80px" alt="over mij" 
                      onmouseover="this.src='iconen/menu/over2.png'" 
                            onmouseout="this.src='iconen/menu/over.png'"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
     <!--Portfolio-->
                    <li id="portfolio">
                     <a href="portfolio.html">
                         <img src="iconen/menu/portfolio.png" height="80px" alt="portfolio" 
                            onmouseover="this.src='iconen/menu/portfolio2.png'" 
                            onmouseout="this.src='iconen/menu/portfolio.png'"/>
                     </a>
                    </li>
              <!--Contact-->
                    <li id="contact">
                     <a href="contact.html">
                         <img src="iconen/menu/contact.png" height="80px" alt="contact" 
                            onmouseover="this.src='iconen/menu/contact2.png'" 
                            onmouseout="this.src='iconen/menu/contact.png'"/>
                        </a>
                   </li>                    
    </div>
   </div>
            
            <div id="homepagina">
    <a href="#">
                <img src="iconen/portfolio/html.png" height="25px" alt="home"
                onmouseover="this.src='iconen/portfolio/html2.png'" 
                onmouseout="this.src='iconen/portfolio/html.png'"> 
                </a>
            </div>
            
            <div id="updates">
             <p id="laatste">Laatste Updates</p>
          </div>
            
            <div id="footer">
                <p id="facebook"> 
                 <a href="https://www.facebook.com/..." target="_blank">
                     <img src="iconen/footer/facebook.png" height="25px" alt="home"
                        onmouseover="this.src='iconen/footer/facebook2.png'" 
                        onmouseout="this.src='iconen/footer/facebook.png'"> 
                    </a>
                </p>
             <p id="email"> 
                   <a href="mailto:....">
                        <img src="iconen/footer/email.png" height="25px" alt="home" 
                        onmouseover="this.src='iconen/footer/email2.png'" 
                        onmouseout="this.src='iconen/footer/email.png'"> 
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>         
     </body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Margin and Padding of <Body> Tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066823/margin-and-padding-of-body-tag)

Answer (score 1):

After floating you should clear:

1.First add "clearfix" class to `<div id="menu">` - `<div id="menu" class="clearfix">`

2.After that add in your style:

```
.clearfix:after { content: "."; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0; }
```

You have another method for clearing - with adding height to `<div id="menu">` or adding `width:100%; overflow:hidden;`.
But the first method with clearfix is the best.

Answer (score 0):

Add class `clear` for a div after navigation bar(i.e., you need to clear the float's used in navigation bar). For this, just add below code after your navigation bar

```
<div class="clear"><!--Clear both--></div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear{
   clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After floating you have to clear.

```
<div class="clear">
<style>
clear: both;
</style>
```